# Android GoogleMap find nearest Places

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Im using  to find nearest "pizzahut" it only give set other nearest places.can any one guide me how to get nearest places.

```
            final URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https").setHost("maps.googleapis.com").setPath("/maps/api/place/search/json");

            builder.addParameter("location", Double.toString(latitude) + "," + Double.toString(longitude));
            builder.addParameter("radius", "1000");
            builder.addParameter("types", "pizza hut");
            builder.addParameter("sensor", "false");
            builder.addParameter("key", "AIzaSyDS8-gY-KmedXVZx1WGOUdBB66z");
            final HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(builder.build());
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpResponse execute = client.execute(request);

            final String response;

                response = EntityUtils.toString(execute.getEntity());

                Log.i("response", response);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below link ?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=mLatitude,mLongitude&radius=5000&types=food&name=cruise&key=API_KEY
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I added `&keyword="pizza+hut"` keyword value.the it returns correct values.any way thanks for the help.

Comment: @sudo, then what's the issue ? Regarding radius ?

Comment: no now problem slove.before i use `&type=` only.i remove the type and add keyword.now its working fine.